# Error while deploying App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I deploy my go application via `appcfg.py --oauth2 --noauth_local_webserver update .`
 Everything was working fine last week, but over the past 3 days and 20+ attempts I keep getting this error:

```
09:11 PM Application: my-app; version: 0-1-0
09:11 PM Host: appengine.google.com
09:11 PM 
Starting update of app: my-app, version: 0-1-0
09:11 PM Getting current resource limits.
09:11 PM Scanning files on local disk.
09:11 PM Cloning 381 application files.
09:11 PM Compilation starting.
09:11 PM Compilation: 315 files left.
09:14 PM Error 500: --- begin server output ---

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
--- end server output ---
09:14 PM Rolling back the update.
Error 500: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

I don't see any errors in the log. I'm well below my quota. I have billing enabled with more than enough money to spare. My project runs locally just fine. I tried pushing an older version of my code and that didn't work either.

I have other App Engine projects that are deploying just fine, just not this one.

Please help! I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Not sure this would help fix it, but to isolate, I'd recommend trying it on another project, or version.

Comment: Just tried it. Definitely works for other projects :/

Comment: Good, so it has something to do with the project then. Did you check the Admin Console to see if there's any errors/quota/billing issue? Anything at all?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the logs. The quota page says everything is "Okay". Just upped the billing to allow for $10/day, although I haven't spent any $ today. I don't see anything wrong :/

Comment: What if you try changing it to a different version and upload. Does it work then?

Comment: Sigh, just upped the version. I'll try again in a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58024/discussion-between-user1161657-and-bero-dotnet).

Comment: Didn't help  :/ Not sure what else to try

Comment: You should contact google, there must be something wrong with your project.

Comment: Looks like that would require Silver support, which is $150 :/

Answer (score 3):

I had too many files I was trying to deploy. By removing one of my larger third-party libraries, I was able to deploy just fine

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
appcfg.py rollback <app-directory>
```

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp)

Then redeploy

Comment: Didn't work :(  Also tried changing the version number to a previous version, rolling back, then deploying. Didn't work either :/

Comment: As a test I'd create a new application, try deploying to the new application id.

Comment: Just tried deploying to a different application id. It also failed to deploy with the same error

Comment: I would roll back to the last version of the code I successfully deployed, if it will deploy to the new app id there's something in the revision, would need more details on what was revised.

Comment: Looks like I'm able to deploy if I include less files XD

Comment: I have a library that adds ~150 files. Including it while deploying causes the issue